# Django on nginx ubuntu server static files in admin not found

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx, ubuntu-server

I have setup my django project on a ubuntu server with nginx webserver.
In my django settings.py file i set:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/static/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    '/var/www/core/frontend/static',
    '/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static',
]
```

whell, in my nginx.conf file i write:

```
server {
    listen  80 default_server;
    listen  [::]:80 default_server;
  }

 # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location /static/ {
    alias /var/www/core/frontend/static/;
}       

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
```

but when i open the admin part of my project i get a lot of 404 error about css and js not found.

Where i have to implement my code for correctly manage static admin file?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you check manually the path to your static files inside `/var/www/core/frontend/static/` and which `/static/` URLs are failing?

Comment: Try to use `root /var/www/core/frontend;` instead of `alias /var/www/core/frontend/static/;`